# IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0 Operation Console No runtime environment deployed in this server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

My server configuration is as follows:

RHEL 6.0
WebSphere 8.5.5
DB2 Database
IBM Mobile First Platform Consumer Edition 7.0

Operation Console loaded fine. Deployed the Project WAR file builded using the ANT task. Restarted the Application server.

The operation console shows "No runtime environment deployed in this server".

[Complete Server Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ecu2v9kif56jibh/SystemOut.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Why provide a partial log instead of a full one?

Comment: Please check now. I am able to access the link posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Required security test 'SubscribeServlet'
>   for resource subscribeServlet' wasn't found in
>   authenticationConfig.xml

Verify your project is up-to-date and is not missing the above.
I can't say for sure that this will correct everything, but it's a starting point.